# ng-file-upload within ngResource ng-multiple progress

Tags: angularjs, ng-file-upload

I have no clue how to dispatch multiple files into one server hit using the ngResource service module.

Below shows passing one file in the callback - that works.

However, if all the files are passed in one call to o.Upload(loParams.files...), Fiddler sees the file count correctly but each hit is missing the data of the file upload.

Then there is the entire seperate issue of showing $progress.

Has anyone besides me played around with this and gotten it working?

```js
var o = $resource('myResource',{}, (
'Upload': {url: 'fileUpload',
   method: 'POST', 
   isArray: false,
   transformRequest: formDataObject,
   head
   });
   return {
Upload: function (loParams, dataCallback, errorCallback) {
 var laResponse = [];

 for (var i = 0; i < loParams.files.length; i++) {
  // copy parameters than add the file before uploading
  var loFileUpload = angular.copy(loParams)
  loFileUpload.files = loParams.files[i];

   oDBC.Upload(loFileUpload, function (response) {
    laResponse.push(response);
   }, function (error) {
         errorCallback(error);
        });
  };
}
```

[Angular.Resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource)

[GitHub :: ng-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload/tree/5c5d7189b0722f0f4e5096cabba680b93205fc82#usage)

Comment: I couldn't get this working either with ng-file-upload. Instead I used BlueImp file upload and converted the jquery plugin to a directive as I found it easier to deal with than their angularjs example.

Comment: To send multiple files you can use `Upload.upload({url: '...', file: files})`